# Filtering array of objects by an out of order array of IDs in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Here's an array of book objects.

```
const books=[
    {
      "id": 1,
      "title": "NPR",
      "url": "https://www.npr.org"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "title": "Google Docs",
      "url": "https://docs.google.com/"
    },
    {
      "title": "Fetch API Docs",
      "url": "https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch",
      "id": 3
    },
    {
      "title": "Yahoo",
      "url": "http://www.yahoo.com",
      "id": 4
    },
    {
      "title": "Google",
      "url": "http://www.google.com",
      "id": 5
    }
  ]
```

And a separate array of IDs

```
const selectedIds = [1, 5, 3]
```

With javascript, how can I filter the books array to just the `selectedIds` (keeping the same order as in `selectedIds`)?

**Final result I'm looking to get:**

```
selectedBooks = [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "title": "NPR",
      "url": "https://www.npr.org"
    },
    {
      "title": "Google",
      "url": "http://www.google.com",
      "id": 5
    },
    {
      "title": "Fetch API Docs",
      "url": "https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch",
      "id": 3
    }
  ]
```

My current code is like this but this preserves the order of the `books` array (i.e. [1, 3, 5]):

```
books.filter(function(item) {
   return selectedIds.includes(item.id);
}
```

Comment: You sure you got the incorrect result. I tested your code on Chromium 77.0.3865.90 and Firefox Quantum 69.0.1 (64-bit) and they seemed to give out the correct order. I can only assume that your const selectedIds's order could be changed to 1, 3, 5 to ensure order preservation. NVM that, I read too quickly, you wanted to keep the order of selectedIDs. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go in the other direction.

```
 selectedIds.map(id => books.find(b => b.id === id))
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const books = [{
    id: 1,
    title: "NPR",
    url: "https://www.npr.org"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: "Google Docs",
    url: "https://docs.google.com/"
  },
  {
    title: "Fetch API Docs",
    url: "https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch",
    id: 3
  },
  {
    title: "Yahoo",
    url: "http://www.yahoo.com",
    id: 4
  },
  {
    title: "Google",
    url: "http://www.google.com",
    id: 5
  }
];

const selectedIds = [1, 5, 3];

const mapped = selectedIds.map(id => {
  return books.find(book => book.id === id);
});

console.log(mapped);
```